# font-face setup with multiple styles

Tags: html, css, fonts, installation, font-face

I have a question about setting up the Roboto font family (multiple styles) on our local server. We cannot link to an outside service for these styles.

I have searched and read a ton of articles and tried a lot but still not getting it to work for me. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. Here is what I have:

- directory setup:

  - html

    - css
    - fonts
    - js
    - sample.html

In the fonts folder I have a folder called "roboto" with all the styles in multiple formats. I also have a stylesheet called "roboto_stylesheet.css" that i have consolidated all the @font-face attributes for all the styles in one place. This file is in the "roboto" folder in fonts.

In my sample.html document I have the path to the "roboto_stylesheet.css" as
    `<link href="fonts/roboto/roboto_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

I created a sample class called ".div1" and another called ".div2" with the font-family as "font-family: roboto_condensedbold;" and "font-family: roboto_condensedregular;" respectively.

In the body I made a simple dev that calls the class. When I go to preview... nothing.

If I copy out the @font-face style out of the "roboto_stylesheet.css" and put it in the head of the document (while disabling the link to the stylesheet) it previews fine.

Like I said, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple but can't see it. All my paths look fine to me.

Hopefully this is clear enough an explanation as I cannot send a link as it's against policy.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your font in `roboto_stylesheet.css` you should have a similar code.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'RobotoFont'; //use this name to set any text font
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto'), url("<font path>.woff2") format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
```

So the `.div1` would look like:

```
.div1{ font-family: 'RobotoFont'; }
```

*Note:* You can check some google fonts declaration [here](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans).

**Edit** As I can see in your comments you specify at the `src` attribute more than one `url()`. I'm not sure if that cause you the problem, but instead of adding more `url()` to the same `@font-face` you better declare the same `@font-face` with the same `font-family` name and only change the source `url()`. As I said I'm not sure this will solve the problem.

**Edit 2:** Also check that the font files had permission 755 or other permission so they can be read and executed

Comment: When I added the font-face info from their stylesheet to my collective stylesheet, it looks like this, and there is one for every varient:

`@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto_condensedregular';
         url('fonts/roboto/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/roboto/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/roboto/RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.svg#roboto_condensedregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}'

Comment: @ba-doyn can you provide the url where you have the site?

Comment: Sorry about that bad comment. Not used to this lack of formatting. I cannot provide a link per company policy.

The font-face structure is different from yours. Mine has the font family, source url for the eot, woff, ttf, and svg formats. It then has the weight and style. Sorry, wish I could display it better but I'm not getting how to add it to this comment field. You can try this for an example. [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-add-multiple-fontface-fonts-that-i-downloaded-from-font-squirrel). Look at the second panel.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. How would I know the unicode-range, or would it be the same for all variants?

Comment: No luck so far. I'll try and whip up a generic page and hierarchy to post.

Comment: Did you check the files permissions on the server?

Comment: Not on a server yet. Doing it local in Eclipse.